# Formatting PhoneRow & Filtering InlinePickerRow

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I am learning how to program in Swift and currently working with the Eureka framework on a project. If anyone could provide some hints/suggestions and brief examples on how to accomplish the following it would be greatly appreciated.

1. Formatting PhoneRow (or any other row really) using a formatter that would insert dashes like 555-123-4567 as the user is typing.
2. How to limit maximum input length on a per-field basis?
3. Filtering InlinePickerRow to allow for a user to narrow down a large list of choices to a subset based on input string in a dynamic small search box.

Thank you in advance! :)